# Ubuntu - Swap partition lose its swap mode

Tags: partitioning, swap, parted

My server (ovh/soyoustart dedicated server) lost one swap partition (i dont know how and when).

Result of parted -l command :

```
Modèle: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
Disque /dev/sda : 2000GB
Taille des secteurs (logiques/physiques): 512B/512B
Table de partitions : gpt

Numéro  Début   Fin     Taille  Système de fichiers  Nom      Fanions
 1      20,5kB  1049kB  1029kB                       primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  21,0GB  21,0GB  ext4                 primary  raid
 3      21,0GB  2000GB  1979GB  ext4                 primary  raid
 4      2000GB  2000GB  536MB                        primary


Modèle: ATA HGST HUS726020AL (scsi)
Disque /dev/sdb : 2000GB
Taille des secteurs (logiques/physiques): 512B/512B
Table de partitions : gpt

Numéro  Début   Fin     Taille  Système de fichiers  Nom      Fanions
 1      20,5kB  1049kB  1029kB                       primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  21,0GB  21,0GB  ext4                 primary  raid
 3      21,0GB  2000GB  1979GB  ext4                 primary  raid
 4      2000GB  2000GB  536MB   linux-swap(v1)       primary
```

/etc/fstab file :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro,relatime      0       1
/dev/md3        /var    ext4    defaults,usrquota,grpquota,relatime     1       2
/dev/sda4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
devtmpfs        /dev    devtmpfs        rw      0       0
```

In standard configuration, the sda4 part use a linux-swap filesystem, like sdb4.

swapon -s :

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb4                               partition       523260  0       -1
```

And for the Raid :
Swap is not "raided":
cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md2 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      20478912 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      1932506048 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 8/15 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Can you help me to reconfigure this partirion ?

Thanks

Comment: Please also add the output of `swapon -S` to your question.

Comment: What kind of RAID are you using? RAID 1 (mirroring)? Is it possible that your swap space is also mirrored? In that case it would be expected that you only see it once.

Comment: Do `grep -i sda4 /var/log/syslog*` and check for what happened. Remake sda4 as swap, `sudo swapon /dev/sda4`. `swapon -s` to verify two swaps.

Comment: Grep return no results. As i said, i dont know when the sda4 swap has crashed.
My problem is that managing servers is not my job, I only do this while waiting to find a network administrator.
All tutorials i found talked about creating a swap partition, with configuring start and end clusters, not only "reconfigure" it

Comment: @z2m Please see my quickie answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try the fastest way to try and get back /dev/sda4 as swap...

`sudo mkswap /dev/sda4`

`sudo swapon /dev/sda4`

`swapon -s` # to verify two swap partitions

Comment: Thanks, i try it tomorrow. Here in France, it is office exit time in 10 minutes, not the good time to crash a server. See you tomorrow

Comment: Hi, i just use your commands and the result seems to be OK.
swapon -s show the 2 partitions of 512 Mo, and htop write xx/1024 MO for the swap.
But parted -l dont write that the sda4 file system as swap (column cell is empty, like in the first post)
Thanks Heynnema for your help

Comment: @z2m Since `parted -i` doesn't show the info that we expect, you may have to do `sudo swapoff /dev/sda4`, then delete /dev/sda4, recreate /dev/sda4 as a swap partition, and repeat my answer, followed by another `parted -i` to verify.